# asp.net mvc assign value in freetextbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

in my .cshtml file, i had a freetextbox for user to input.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FreeText)
```

How can i assign a value in the textbox such as "Type here", when user click the textbox, the default text will disappear ?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: You can either use HTML5 or use an existing javascript module to do this for you (what you are looking for is "watermark").

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this In View 
<input id="FreeText" name="FreeText" type="text" value="Type Here"/>
also include the java script given below
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FreeText').val('Type Here');
    $('#FreeText').focus(function () {
        var vlu = $(this).val();
        if (vlu == '' || vlu == 'Type Here') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        else {
            var char = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(char);
        }

    });
$('#FreeText').blur(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '' || value == 'Type Here') {
            $(this).val('Type Here');
        }
        else {
            var char = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(char);
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in HTML5 you can use the `placeholder`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type here" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HMG4W/

or

```
var placeholder ="Type here";
$(":input").val(placeholder);
$(':input').bind({
  focus: function() {
    $(this).val(" ");
  },
  blur: function() {
    $(this).val(placeholder);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HMG4W/2/

Answer (score 1):

In MVC5 try to follow this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FreeText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Type Here" } })
```